# Delphi: Possible to do unit initialization conditionally?

Tags: delphi, module, initialization, gdi+

My application can be started as `Master` or `Worker`, which is controlled by a startup parameter.

```
program MyApp;
uses
  SysUtils, Forms, WorkerForm, MasterForm;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  //if ParamStr(1) = 'WorkerProcess' then
  if FindCmdLineSwitch('--WorkerProcess') then
    Application.CreateForm(TWorkerForm, WorkerForm)
  else
    Application.CreateForm(TMasterForm, MasterForm);
  Application.Run;
end;
```

The master process can fork worker processes. If a worker process cannot be started in 3 seconds, the master process will show an error. Recently I included GDIPOBJ to the application, so that a worker process cannot be forked on time.

**I have fixed the problem by extending the wait time. But as a worker process does not have UI, so that it does not require Gdi+ stuff. I am very curious to ask all dear Delphi experts, if it is possible load a unit conditionally or initialize a unit conditionally.**

My current solution is copy the unit to my project directory and move the code to a method `InitGidplusStartup`. When I create a `MasterProcess`, I have to explicitly call the method.

```
procedure InitGdiplusStartup;
begin
  if not IsLibrary then
  begin
    // Initialize StartupInput structure
    StartupInput.DebugEventCallback := nil;
    StartupInput.SuppressBackgroundThread := False;
    StartupInput.SuppressExternalCodecs   := False;
    StartupInput.GdiplusVersion := 1;

    GdiplusStartup(gdiplusToken, @StartupInput, nil);
  end;
end;

initialization
(*
  if not IsLibrary then
  begin
    // Initialize StartupInput structure
    StartupInput.DebugEventCallback := nil;
    StartupInput.SuppressBackgroundThread := False;
    StartupInput.SuppressExternalCodecs   := False;
    StartupInput.GdiplusVersion := 1;

    GdiplusStartup(gdiplusToken, @StartupInput, nil);
  end;
*)
```

---

```
program MyApp;
uses
  GDIPOBJ{INCLUDE MODIFIED VERSION FIRST AND I KNOW THE RISK}, 
  SysUtils, Forms, WorkerForm, MasterForm;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  if FindCmdLineSwitch('--WorkerProcess') then
    Application.CreateForm(TWorkerForm, WorkerForm)
  else
  begin
    InitGdiplusStartup;
    Application.CreateForm(TMasterForm, MasterForm);
  end;
  Application.Run;
end;
```

I know it is not a standard approach. I am just want to understand the unit initialization and its limitations. Please do not blame me.

Comment: Hack warning: instead of moving the code from the initialization section of the unit, which can break things that depend on the initialization (order) having executed as expected, you could just add a check for your commandline parameter. And please use `FindCmdLineSwitch` to do so (you will have to add a hyphen or a slash to your 'WorkerProcess' value) so you do not tie everybody to an exact order in which to specify command line parameters.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Thanks for the tip of using `FindCmdLineSwitch`. BTW: I know moving code from the initialization section is not a good thing, so I decided to ask for help here. No idea why it deserves a down vote.

Comment: Why don't you fix the real problem which is why your WorkerProcess does not start

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I fork a worker process by using `ShellExecuteEx` with mask `SEE_MASK_WAITFORINPUTIDLE`. If the worker process cannot be started in 3 seconds, the master process will show an error. When I include GDIPOBJ, `GdiplusStartup` will initialize a `StartupInput`. It prevents my process to be forked within 3 seconds.

Comment: So let's try to fix that

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I can do a periodical check to wait for my worker process to be forked, so that I do not have to do any dirty thing to GdiPlus stuff. I'm curious to see if there is a way to initialize GDIPOBJ conditionally, so I asked the question. One benefit is that, the worker process has nothing to do with GdiPlus, I do not want any GdiPlus intialization consequentially. Anyway, thanks for participate.

Comment: GdiPlus init cannot be done conditionally. You'd need to recompile the unit to make that init conditional.

Comment: Even without GDI+, spinning up a new process isn't exactly a cheap operation. Consider allowing your workers to be persistent, so they can handle multiple commands in sequence. Then you don't need to worry as much about how long it takes to start because you won't be paying that price as often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unit initialization sections are executed unconditionally. So, I can see the following options that could be used to solve your problem:

1. Change your program to be resilient to the worker process executing gdipobj initialization.
2. Create two versions of your program, one with, and one without gdipobj.
3. Put the code that uses gdipobj in a separate module that is only loaded conditionally.
4. Replace the gdipobj unit with a version that only executes the initialization section conditionally.

The latter option is quite easy to do. Take a copy of the gdipobj unit, and include it in your project's source tree. Make sure that this unit is referenced in the .dpr file. Modify the `initialization` section of this copy of the unit to skip initialization based on your condition.

Comment: Could you explain more about point 3? How does a separate module looks like and how to load it? Thanks.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 It's the same as Uwe's final paragraph. Put the code that use gdipobj into a DLL or a package and link to it at runtime rather than load time.

Answer (score 2):

Units are not loaded at runtime, they are linked during compile time. If you want to distinguish with a command line parameter, the unit has to be present whether it is used or not. The compiler cannot know the runtime parameter, so it has to link the unit anyway.

If you can live with the separation of the initialization code, you can do with that. Be aware that the time the code is executed during the initialization sequence might be different when you go this way.

Another, probably cumbersome, approach would be to put the offending unit into a package that is only loaded on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `DDetours library`  https://code.google.com/p/delphi-detours-library/wiki/DDetours
to patch the call to `GDIplusStartup`.

Add this unit first in your project.

```
Unit PatchGDI;

Interface

uses
  WinApi.GDIPAPI, DDetours;

Implementation

var
  TrampolineGdiplusStartup : function(out token: ULONG; input: PGdiplusStartupInput;
   output: PGdiplusStartupOutput): Status; stdcall = nil;

function InterceptGdiplusStartup(out token: ULONG; input: PGdiplusStartupInput;
   output: PGdiplusStartupOutput): Status; stdcall;
begin
  Result := GdiplusNotInitialized;
end;

Initialization

  if ParamStr(1) = 'WorkerProcess' then
    @TrampolineGdiplusStartup := InterceptCreate(@GdiplusStartup, @InterceptGdiplusStartup);

end.
```

<strike>Disclaimer, untested, but you get the idea.</strike>

Here is a sample project. Run it in debug mode, and you can see that `GDIplusStartup` is intercepted and that the initialization code in GDIPOBJ is calling the intercepted procedure:

```
program Project124;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  PatchGDI in 'PatchGDI.pas',
  GDIPOBJ;

begin
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I tried with no success. Maybe the keyword `delayed` of `GidplusStartup` fails the detour approach. `function GdiplusStartup; external WINGDIPDLL name 'GdiplusStartup' delayed;`

Comment: Are you sure you declared the `PatchGDI` unit before `GDIPOBJ` in your project file? I can't see why my approach would fail.